# How to move item text on index page with custom CSS?

Tags: css, squarespace

I would like to move these titles below the image. The theme is York. Any ideas?

[image]

https://robert-holgate.squarespace.com/projects

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height on this, once that's done, I actually like the style of it.
If you cannot find this code Command+F in your code editor, then search height or one of the class names in the image

[image]

However, more to the point of the question, then add:

```
.index-item-title {
   margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `bottom: 0;` with `bottom: 91px;` in

```
.index-item-image-alignment-center.index-item-image-crop .index-item-image-wrapper.content-fill, .index-item-image-alignment-left.index-item-image-crop .index-item-image-wrapper.content-fill, .index-item-image-alignment-right.index-item-image-crop .index-item-image-wrapper.content-fill {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: none;
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 91px;
    left: 0;
}
```

and `bottom: 5vw` with `bottom: -2vw` in

```
.index-item-title-alignment-bottom.full-bleed-index.site-outer-padding-medium .index-item-text-wrapper {
    bottom: -2vw;
}
```